# Cucumber support for Aptana

Tags: cucumber, aptana

I am using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.6.201110251455 for developing ruby + cucumber web automation framework. Aptana has decent support for Ruby, but it does not   support cucumber features files. I would need a .feature extention and support from Aptana.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this out: https://github.com/aptana/cucumber.ruble
You may find it for useful

Answer (score 1):

I am running the latest version of Aptana (3.2.1) and it now has support for tab completion, and various other commands. However, I still don't have syntax highlighting. I submitted a bug. I'll report back when I find out more.